# Getting ORA-00923 error, but can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

IBS'm MDM tool has generated some Oracle SQL that is giving me a "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" error and I'm not versed enough in Oracle to figure out what's wrong.  The SQL in question is:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5)
SELECT NEXTVAL FOR SEQ1, 'TCRM', 'XStudentBObjExt', T.Field4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM Table T
JOIN Table2 G
    ON T.GROUP_NAME = G.GROUP_NAME
WHERE G.OBJECT_NAME = 'Name';
```

My guess is that Workbench is writing for a slightly older version of Oracle.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: "ORA-xxxxx" is an Oracle DB error, not an IBM DB error.

Comment: You're right.  At one point, we were doing this with DB2.  I'll correct the question.

Comment: It took a while, but your comment got into my brain and made me look again at what I was doing and sure enough, I was using the DB2 code that MDM generates, and not the Oracle SQL (MDM creates SQL for Oracle, DB2, and zos).  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part

```
NEXTVAL FOR SEQ1
```

is wrong. In Oracle it should be:

```
SEQ1.NEXTVAL
```

You can read more about sequences [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253)

Comment: I just realized I was using the generated DB2 SQL instead of the generated Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0):

MDM generates SQL for three different databases: DB2, Oracle, and zos.  Unfortunately, I used the wrong set of SQL.